# RPL implementation for NS2

Tags: routes, ns2

I am trying to find the 6lowpan module in NS2. I didn't find any RPL or 6lowpan module in ns2. How can I implement the same in ns2? How can I get the program code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying the code in ns2, you can refer contiki OS or Riot OS for that purpose. including examples with source code, you can do lot many things.